# Rate Limited with Discord.py

Tags: python, flask, discord, discord.py, rate-limiting

I'm currently trying to create my own Discord bot using Discord.py. I tried to follow many websites and youtubers to set up a replit account and uptimerobot to keep my bot awake. Indeed, my bot is alive for a few hours, but then, it is rate limited.
[image: this is my uptimerobot setting]

[image: This is the error I got]
Can anyone help me out with this please.

This is my code taken from FreeCodeCamp to host it online

```
from flask import Flask #this the web sersive
from threading import Thread #run multiple threads

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "The bot is running on web server..."
def run():
  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target = run)
  t.start()
```

I did tried to use 'kill 1' as someone recommended on StackOverflow but the problem is not fixed

this is from file restarter.py

```
from time import sleep
from os import system
sleep(7)
system("python main.py")
```

this is in main where I tried to connect with the web server and make it work non-stop

```
...
# Connect with web server
keep_alive()

# Hide TOKEN for privacy
try:
    client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
except discord.errors.HTTPException:
    print("\n\n\nBLOCKED BY RATE LIMITS\nRESTARTING NOW\n\n\n")
    system("python restarter.py")
    system('kill 1')
```

Comment: There is some cool-off period after rate limit is reached , any idea regarding what it is in this case

Comment: If you host your bot on repl.it, you share a single IP with lots and lots of other people and that's because you get ratelimited. If you want to avoid this, host the bot yourself, or find a better host.

Comment: @moinierer3000 Is there any platform other than Repl.it that you reccomend ? I'm quite new to this field

Comment: You have to pay for pretty much all decent ones, like DigitalOcean or Hetzner, but for example GCP (Google), Azure (Microsoft) or AWS (Amazon) have free tiers that last a year. I can also recommend getting a cheap raspberry pi (or similar) to host it yourself.